# German character ß uppercase and lowercase

Tags: encoding, uppercase, lowercase

I have a problem with German character "ß".

After some research I have found that this character transforms into "SS" when word style is uppercase. Also tried this by myself.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

**Maybe there is some work-around to make "ß" uppercase?**
Some parameters that could be useful that I'm using now:
-font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
-Encoding : utf-8.

Thanks

**EDIT** : this is not js question, I have product name that shown incorrectly. Font added via css :)

Comment: JavaScript's `toUpperCase` does the same thing (`ß` => `SS`), at least on Chrome. [Looks like there was no upper case for that letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Upper_case), but one was [added to Unicode](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=1E9E) in 2008. It's a subtle distinction: `ß` => `ẞ` (and the font I'm seeing that in has a rubbish version of it).

Comment: Is this a javascript question?  If so, please add the appropriate tag to improve the searchability of the question.

Comment: @gariepy this is not js question. I have edited the question :)

Comment: This was helpful to know that the UC conversion was happening to others.  Thanks for posting,

Comment: See here: https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/CaseFolding.txt